# Is there a universal config file for .Net Standard 2.0 Class Library?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have a Class Library that I'm converting to a .Net Standard 2 class library in order to also use in ASP.Net Core 2.0 projects.

The library has always read from a config file items such as SMTP settings, connection strings etc.

In Web Projects it finds these values in **web.config**.

In Console/WinForms it finds these values in **app.config**.

**Is there an equivalent config file for .Net Core 2.0 projects that "just works" like the previous examples?**

I assume the answer is no, but looking for best way to handle this given the library is used across the organization, so maintaining backwards compatibility is important.

Comment: Is your question confused? The title asks about .net std, the bold bit asks about .net core

Comment: @casius .net core 2 is anders implementation of .net standard 2.

Comment: @MattJohnson I agree, but in my current situation we have an existing library in heavy use that "just works" since system.configuration gets the values from app.config or web.config. Is there a way to use DI to push a config file into a .net core project so that this library can find these values in the same way ?

Comment: @T.S. - You're correct.  My understanding has expanded since I originally wrote that.  I have deleted my comment.  Please do the same so we can clean up this thread.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Turns out [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager) was added back in .NETStandard 2.0.

Just pull it in from nuget and compile the **.NETStandard 2.0** class library project.

Then, the library will work across projects using standard config files:

- **Net Core 2.0** projects use app.config
- **Web projects** work from web.config
- **Console** and **Windows apps** work with app.config

Comment: Will this support appsettings.json in a .net core app?

Comment: @gperrego this solution is a universal configuration specifically for your .NETStandard 2+ class library that you can then reference within your .Net Core app. appsettings.json is the configuration specific for your .net core app. They are not related.

Comment: Could you provide the documentation that show `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager' being part of .NET Standard 2.0?

Comment: I have to create a client in dotnetstandard that needs to be consumed in .net framework 4.5. Since dotnetstandard 1.1 only supports this, so I am creating my client in netstandard 1.1. but I can find any alternative to read app.config file in that. How can I read app.config file in netstandard 1.1 application?

Comment: Click the link in the answer and expand the Dependencies section. You'll see there that it's supported (`.NETStandard 2.0`). | @G.Stoynev

Answer (score 12):

.Net Core revised configuration approach greatly.

You don't call `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someSetting"]` anymore whenever you need value for some setting. Instead you load configuration on application startup with `ConfigurationBuilder`. There could be multiple configuration sources (json or/and xml configuration file, environment variables, command line, Azure Key Vault, ...).

Then you build your configuration and pass strongly typed setting objects wrapped into `IOption<T>` to consuming classes.

Here is a basic idea of how it works:

```
//  Application boostrapping

ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json");
var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

//  IServiceCollection services

services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<SomeSettings>(configuration.GetSection("SomeSection"));

//  Strongly typed settings

public class SomeSettings
{
    public string SomeHost { get; set; }

    public int SomePort { get; set; }
}

//  Settings consumer

public class SomeClient : ISomeClient
{
    public SomeClient(IOptions<SomeSettings> someSettings)
    {
        var host = someSettings.Value.SomeHost;
        var port = someSettings.Value.SomePort;
    }
}

//  AppSettings.json

{
  "SomeSection": {
    "SomeHost": "localhost",
    "SomePort": 25
  }
}
```

For more details check article [Configure an ASP.NET Core App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration).

I'm afraid that it will be difficult (trying to avoid word 'impossible') to maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: Why wrap the settings object into IOptions, why not pass the settings object 'SomeSettings' directly?